# IE6: absolute positioned element's width:100% stretches to only it's parent's width that is not positioned

Tags: css, position, internet-explorer-6, css-position, percentage

Sorry for my English.
This can be too simple question, but I couldn't find the answer in my search result :(
I want to stretch DIV to full window, being in other small DIV.
It works well in all modern browser but IE6.
I usually don't support IE6 but my client demanded it.
the code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ko" lang="ko" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <style type="text/css">
        #outter {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            background: #00f;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
        #inner {
            background: #f00;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 20px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="outter">
            <div id="inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding `body{ width:100%; height:100%}` and take a look at this. It may help you - http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/